# leer un archivo de texto y usar la primera fila para crear un arreglo bidimensional c#

Tags: c#

tengo este .txt lo que quiero es poder usar la primera fila del archivo como tamaño para crear un arreglo bidimensional en este caso 7 seria el numero de columnas y 210 filas  y despues guardar todas las filas que siguen del txt  en ese arreglo, en este caso los datos son los numeros decimales que estan separados por espacios en blanco

```
210 7
15.26   14.84   0.871   5.763   3.312   2.221   5.22
14.88   14.57   0.8811  5.554   3.333   1.018   4.956
14.29   14.09   0.905   5.291   3.337   2.699   4.825
13.84   13.94   0.8955  5.324   3.379   2.259   4.805
16.14   14.99   0.9034  5.658   3.562   1.355   5.175
14.38   14.21   0.8951  5.386   3.312   2.462   4.956
14.69   14.49   0.8799  5.563   3.259   3.586   5.219
14.11   14.1    0.8911  5.42    3.302   2.7 5
16.63   15.46   0.8747  6.053   3.465   2.04    5.877
```

tenia este codigo en c++  y la verdad no entiendo bien como hacerlo en c# solo necesito el arreglo con los datos para continuar el resto de mi codigo porian ayudarme

```
ifstream database;
database.open("irisdata.txt");

if(database.fail())
{
    cout<<"error";
    getch();
    exit(0);
}
database>>fil>>col;
for(int i=0;i<fil;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<col;j++)
    {
        database>>a[i][j];

    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué intentaste hasta ahora, por más que no funcione? Me imagino que con tanta información en la web, se puede iniciar por algo

Comment: se mas o menos como guardar los datos sin nececidad de usar los parametros, pero lo que quiero es usar los parametros y  no se  como tomar la primera fila conseguir el 210 y el 7

Answer (score 1):

Intentaré escribir el código de forma que refleje la estructura de C++, con la intención que esto facilite entenderlo.

El primer inconveniente al traducir es que al intentar abrir un archivo al que no tienes permisos o que no existe vas a tener una excepción en lugar de un código de error que puedas verificar con un `if`. Por tanto `if(database.fail())` se convertirá un un `try`.

Por otro lado, voy a necesitar utilizar `FileReader`. Aunque `FileStream` ofrece una interfaz de nivel más bajo, `StreamReader` se aproxima más a `<<`.

Primera parte del código:

```
StreamReader database;
try
{
    database = new StreamReader("irisdata.txt");
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    Console.WriteLine("error");
    Console.ReadKey();
    return 0;
}
```

La excepción que recibes puede ser `SecurityException` o una de varias `IOException` (notablemente `FileNotFoundException`).

Para que `return 0;` sea equivalente a `exit(0);` estoy asumiendo que el código se encuentra en `int Main()`. En otro caso el equivalente es `Environment.Exit(0);`.

---

Ahora el problema es que .NET no incluye la funcionalidad de leer una palabra a la vez (leer hasta el espacio). Quiero anotar si lees varios `char` uno por uno, es mejor definir la gramática con una lista de caracteres validos. Sin embargo en este caso optaré por la forma fácil (leer toda la linea y separar por espacios):

```
var valores = database.ReadLine().Split(' ');
```

Pero tenemos `string`, necesitamos `int`...

```
var fil = int.Parse(valores[0]);
var col = int.Parse(valores[1]);
```

Esta es la parte en la que te digo que consideres que pasaría sin la primera linea del archivo no tiene un espacio. O que pasaría si no contiene valores numéricos. O que pasaría si por el idioma de la maquina el formato de número no coincide con lo que hay en el archivo... no te importó cuando escribiste C++, así que te doy un código C# que ignora esas preocupaciones.

Continuamos con el `for`:

```
for(int i=0;i<fil;i++)
{
    var columnas = database.ReadLine().Split(new char[]{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    for(int j=0;j<col;j++)
    {
        a[i][j] = columnas[j];
    }
}
```

De nuevo estoy leyendo una linea y separando por espacio. Sin embargo estoy utilizando una sobrecarga de `Split` que recibe un parametro `StringSplitOptions`. La razón de esto es que al parecer las lineas del archivo usan más de un espacio como separación.

Si debe ser una cantidad especifica de espacios puedes utilizar:

```
var columnas = database.ReadLine().Split(new string[]{"   "}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Sin embargo la versión que coloqué antes es más versátil.

---

No sé el tipo de datos de `a`, de hecho no veo que lo hayas alojado memoria para `a` en C++ (eso puede ser un problema en C++, tal vez tienes una vulnerabilidad de desbordamiento de buffer). Al respecto, en C# probablemente quieras definir `a` como un arreglo 2D (antes del `for`):

```
var a = new string[fil, col];
```

Y lo usarías de esta forma:

```
a[i, j] = columnas[j];
```

Por supuesto, es posible que quieras un arreglo de `float` o `double` u otra cosa. En ese caso puedes utilizar `float.Parse`, `double.Parse` o el metodo de conversión que corresponda.

---

<strike>Ahora, yo observo en el ejemplo que hay una linea que tiene menos elementos:</strike>

```
(...)
14.69   14.49   0.8799  5.563   3.259   3.586   5.219
14.11   14.1    0.8911  5.42    3.302   2.7 5
16.63   15.46   0.8747  6.053   3.465   2.04    5.877 
(...)
```

Al utilizar `database.ReadLine().Split(' ')` tendrás tantos elementos como haya en la linea. Esto significa que al hacer `columnas[j]` puedes tener un `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Como solución sugiero colocar el `for` interno de esta forma:

```
for(int j=0;j<Math.Min(col, columnas.Length);j++)
```

Eso evitará que intentes leer más allá del final del arreglo. También significa que en `a` el valor que falta quedará con el valor por defecto (`null` si es `string`, `0` si es numérico, etc...).

---

Por ultimo hay que cerrar el archivo. Tu no cerraste el archivo en C++! Para que no se nos olvide cerrar el archivo, y para asegurarnos que se cierre incluso en caso de error, utiliza un bloque `using`. Alternativamente puedes usar un bloque `try...finally`.

Sin embargo, yo diría que colocaras todo el código dentro del `try` que vimos al principio...

```
try
{
    using (var database = new StreamReader("irisdata.txt"))
    {
        // resto del código ...
    }
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    Console.WriteLine("error");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Quiero agregar que en .NET los bloques `try` son declarativos. Para el código entrar en bloque `try` no es una instrucción, y por tanto no tiene ningún impacto en el desempeño (a menos que ocurra la excepción).

Comment: muchas gracias no entendia bien en los tutorales de lectura de archivos pero tu me lo explicaste muy claro

Comment: por cierto el arreglo lo declare en una funcion como int y acerca de la linea que dices que tiene 1 elemento menos de hecho esta completa  solo que el ultimo dato de esa fila es entero y por eso parece que hay uno menos

Comment: @sherpensglen ya veo, no me había fijado.

Comment: aun asi muchas gracias por explicarme